# Why is my byte array different after converting to an xml string and back to byte array?

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, arrays

I have the following piece of code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("test.pdf");
byte[] info = reader.Metadata;

string xml = new UTF8Encoding().GetString(info);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
doc.WriteTo(tx);
string str = sw.ToString();
byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

Why is bytedata different than info?

For my test data, info is byte[4093] and bytedata is byte[1498].

Comment: Well have you *looked* at the text to see what's different? Maybe you're getting indentation for example...

Comment: My first guess would be that the original might have had a lot of whitespace in that was not in the subsequent one. Or maybe namespaces were written more succinctly. Any reason why you can't look at the before and after to see what the differences are? And if you still don't know why the differences having found them then you could then ask that more specific question.

Comment: `XmlDocument` [will not preserve whitespace by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx), and `XmlTextWriter` [will not indent by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.formatting(v=vs.110).aspx) so these will likely account for the reduction in size.  As @JonSkeet says, though, why not actually *look* at `xml` and `str` to see what the difference is?

Comment: Ok. I think it is the whitespace. By using doc.PreserveWhitespace = true; I mananged to get the difference to a lot less.